# Use compile-time, static typed FieldDefinition when calling AddToSet

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the MongoDb C# driver and trying to add a new element to an array of a sub-document.

My model is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": "5572f0fed11c38098833e306",
    "LastActionId": 11,
    "Suggestions": [
        {
            "_id": "48f366ccb900405bb393484ef2c43ca9",
            "VotersIds": [
                "5571b4d7d11c381d8026e848",
                "6571b4d7d11c381d8026e848"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am adding a new voter id to a specific suggestion. This code works fine:

```
var builderUpdate = Builders<Meeting>.Update;
var update = builderUpdate.Inc(m => m.LastActionId, 1).AddToSet("Suggestions.$.VotersIds", userId);

var builderFilter = Builders<Meeting>.Filter;
var filter = builderFilter.Eq(m => m.Id, meetingId) & builderFilter.Eq("Suggestions._id", suggestionId);

await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

**However, I don't want to hardcode `Suggestions.$.VotersIds` and `Suggestions._id`**

I want to use the compile-time, static typed api, but I can't seem to find it.   Do I have to use the hardcode version?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the $ by using m => m.Suggestions.ElementAt(-1).VotersIds. However, the second one is tricky and we don't currently have a solution for it. You can see the feature request here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1309.

Craig